# VS Code hotkey for putting a semicolon at the end a line in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Currently it's a small pain to do <kbd>End</kbd>,<kbd>;</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> when I  need to put a semicolon at the end of a line when the cursor is somewhere in the middle. The optimal in my opinion would be to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to put a semicolon at the end of the current line and immediately after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as it would be language agnostic.

Any way I could achieve this functionality? Improvements to the workflow are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could cook something up with [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands). Ex. (in keybindings.json, which you open with `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "cursorEnd",
            { "command": "type", "args": {"text": ";"} },
            // TODO (optional) now take your pick from the following:
            // "lineBreakInsert",               // inserts new line without moving cursor to new line
            // "editor.action.insertLineAfter", // inserts new line after current line regardless of where cursor is in current line, and moves cursor to the start of the new line
        ],
    },
},
```

I wish `cursorUndo` or `workbench.action.navigateBackInEditLocations` could be used to move the cursor back to the pre-move-to-end position, but sadly, no (typing kills the cursor history). But courtesy of Mark in the comments, if you want to return to the starting cursor position, you can use this trick:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "editor.action.setSelectionAnchor",
            "cursorEnd",
            { "command": "type", "args": {"text": ";"} },
            "editor.action.goToSelectionAnchor",
            "editor.action.cancelSelectionAnchor",
        ],
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect for my needs. I tweaked the key to `"key": "ctrl+,",`. My only issue is that uncommenting `"cursorUndo",` does nothing. Any reason why that is?

Comment: @Managor oh interesting. sorry I didn't test that. TIL typing kills cursor history.

Comment: If you want to return the cursor to its original position, you can wrap the commands with `"editor.action.setSelectionAnchor",` and `"editor.action.goToSelectionAnchor"`, `"editor.action.cancelSelectionAnchor"` after inserting the `;`.  One of my tricks...